# Smaato fill rate, problems

Tags: fill, rate, smaato

Okay, I just updated my app the other day, adding Smaato. I'm in the US and I constantly got error 42's which is that no ads are available no big surprise in the US. And the SMAATO testing id's worked fine. So I published it (with a fallback to adrotator(pubcenter,adduplex) in any case my fill rate with Smaato is crap. And narrowing down the stats on their site for the past 3 days (it says I have 26,569 AD requests, and 26 impressions. I would think then I'd have a fill rate of like 1% maybe 2%. It states I have a fill rate of 99.09% (which would have meant that it provided 99% of the Ads. I know from telemetry data that most of my add requests to Smaato have gotten error 42's. I've tried contacting support for days (actually even before I published my app I was trying to get ahold of someone) Has anyone else been having issues? there's no forums,etc. and their site support is crap (especially since I've put in 3 tickets, sent 2 emails and still haven't even gotten a thing saying that they saw the ticket.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, As an FYI I've actually corresponded with Smaato and apparently they don't support any advertising that is not on a mobile device. It seems that in their SDK they have something that reports back whether the device is connected via a cell connection. If it is on a cellular connection they provide an advertisement. If not then they don't, and this won't change for the foreseeable future.